# Is this Java small pubsub memory implementation correct and effective?

Tags: java, multithreading

We want to provide a simple Redis pub/sub alternative in memory for [our software](https://github.com/ICIJ/datashare). So we implemented this :

```
public class MemoryDataBus implements DataBus {
    private final Map<Consumer<Message>, MessageListener> subscribers = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void publish(final Channel channel, final Message message) {
        Message nonNullMessage = requireNonNull(message, "cannot publish a null message");
        subscribers.values().stream().filter(l -> l.hasSubscribedTo(channel)).forEach(l -> l.accept(nonNullMessage));
    }

    @Override
    public void subscribe(final Consumer<Message> subscriber, final Channel... channels) throws InterruptedException {
        MessageListener listener = new MessageListener(subscriber, channels);
        subscribers.put(subscriber, listener);
        listener.loopUntilShutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public void unsubscribe(Consumer<Message> subscriber) {
        ofNullable(subscribers.remove(subscriber)).ifPresent(l -> {
            l.accept(new ShutdownMessage());
        });
    }

    private static class MessageListener implements Consumer<Message> {
        private final Consumer<Message> subscriber;
        private final LinkedHashSet<Channel> channels;
        final AtomicReference<Message> message = new AtomicReference<>();

        public MessageListener(Consumer<Message> subscriber, Channel... channels) {
            this.subscriber = subscriber;
            this.channels = asSet(channels);
        }

        boolean hasSubscribedTo(Channel channel) {
            return channels.contains(channel);
        }

        @Override
        public void accept(Message message) {
            subscriber.accept(message);
            synchronized (this.message) {
                this.message.set(message);
                this.message.notify();
            }
        }

        boolean shutdownAsked() {
            Message message = this.message.get();
            return message != null && message.type == Message.Type.SHUTDOWN;
        }

        void loopUntilShutdown() throws InterruptedException {
            synchronized (message) {
                while (!shutdownAsked()) {
                    message.wait();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've removed unnecessary code that brings some noise (logs, couters) the source code [is here](https://github.com/ICIJ/datashare-api/blob/master/src/main/java/org/icij/datashare/com/MemoryDataBus.java).

Our unit tests are green, and manual testing shows no regression compared to redis. But as we also know how difficult it is to make a correct thread safe implementation we want to verify with threading experts :

- the correctness of it (for example the value returned by shutdownAsked)
- if the contention could be improved
- if there could be a better implementation of it

PS : must add that the question has been originally posted [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681774/is-this-java-small-pubsub-memory-implementation-correct-and-effective).

Comment: _"must add that the question has been originally posted on SO."_ Please delete it there then. Cross posting is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Well I see no Javadoc, so we have no idea how to call this or work with it in a thread safe manner.  To illustrate a bit further, look at the Javadoc for [JFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html), right there it says `Warning: Swing is not thread safe. For more information see Swing's Threading Policy.` So that's it, thread safety is "it ain't" and they have a published policy how to interact with it.  So, what's your policy how a caller will interact with this code?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ a kind user has discussed and provide useful information about this code on SO. I can't delete this information.

Comment: @markspace I even removed portions of code because my need here is thread correctness, not how I could add javadoc or comments

Comment: I ended up with a more generic implementation without dependencies and with a main to show how to use it @markspace see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bamthomas/069f563b2d5216ee9ee016d3f8443d8b)

Comment: In the given architecture the stream operation could benefit from `.unordered().parallel()`. However, even with parallel, the operation if far too expensive. Would it be possible to make something like `Channel::getAllSubscribers` ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `requireNonNull(...)` is [`java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T,java.lang.String)) which throws an exception if `null`, then there is no need to have a separate local variable for the return value.

Assuming `ofNullable(...)` is [`java.util.Optional.ofNullable(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable(T)), then I would recommend removing the usage here because the code can be simplified:

```java
// ofNullable(...).ifPresent(l -> ...);
// Simplified:
MyClass result = ...
if (result != null) {
    ...
}
```

<s>It looks like your locking in `MessageListener` will cause a deadlock:</s>

1. <s>`MemoryDataBus.subscribe(...)` calls `loopUntilShutdown` which synchronizes on `message`</s>
2. <s>`MemoryDataBus.publish(...)` calls `accept` which has to wait because lock on `message` is still held, preventing it from updating `message`</s>

Edit: No deadlock occurs because `Object.wait()` is used which releases ownership of the monitor (here field `message`).

Comment: How does `MemoryDataBus.subscribe(...)` call `accept` ?

Comment: @BrunoThomas, sorry that was a typo, I meant "`MemoryDataBus.publish(...)` calls `accept`". I have corrected it now.

Comment: hmm. thank you for your answer. I think it actually works because it is the same thread (for each message consumer), that is entering the two synchronized blocks. But maybe you have a use case in mind that I don't see. Could you write a test that shows the scenario (for ex like I did here https://github.com/ICIJ/datashare-api/blob/master/src/test/java/org/icij/datashare/com/MemoryDataBusTest.java) ?

Comment: @BrunoThomas, thank you for providing the code. My previous statement was wrong, I completely missed that `Object.wait()` releases the monitor, so no deadlock can occur. I am very sorry for the confusion my statement caused.